# Finding neighboring pixels in a 2D array without exceeding bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking to find neighboring pixels in a 2D array. Using a formula for euclidean distance, and an arbitrary number, I want to find if the 'color difference' between a pixel, pix1, and the neighboring pixel, pix2, is > 65. If so, change neighbor pixel, pix2, to black, otherwise change to white. Now, I realize a pixel can have up to 8 neighbors in a 2D array.

For this homework, I was given other .java files which prompt you to select any image, and using this program I'm writing, will output a black and white image based on the mentioned 'color difference.'

I implemented, albeit very inefficient, series of if-statements to check for bounds in the 2D array, but there's a mistake somewhere that I can't seem to find.

edit: no longer get out of bounds, but null pointer errors.

When I forgo a return statement.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type Color[][]
```

I don't know what it should be returning, all I want is to change pixel colors. Clearly objects are an area I lack understanding.

Also when adding a return statement: 'return result', I get a null pointer exception, where it references other java files

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ImageConverter.arrayToBufferedImage(ImageConverter.java:45)
    at ImageWriter.writeImage(ImageWriter.java:16)
    at ImageProcessing.processImage(ImageProcessing.java:164)
    at ImageProcessing.main(ImageProcessing.java:186)
```

Updated code:

```
    import java.awt.Color;

public class OperationContour implements OperationImage {

public Color[][] doOperation(Color[][] imagingArray) {
    int numberOfRows = imagingArray.length;
    int numberOfColumns = imagingArray[0].length;

    Color[][] result = new Color[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {

            Color pix1 = imagingArray[i][j];
            Color pix2 = imagingArray[i][j];

            double colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));

            // BELOW
            if (i < numberOfRows-1 && j>0) {
                pix2 = imagingArray[i+1][j];
                colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));
                if (colorDifference > 65) {
                    pix1 = Color.BLACK;}
                else {
                    pix1 = Color.WHITE; 


        // #2 BOTTOM RIGHT
            if (j < numberOfColumns-1 && i < numberOfRows-1){
                pix2 = imagingArray[i+1][j+1];
                colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));
                if (colorDifference > 65) {
                    pix1 = Color.BLACK;}
                else {
                    pix1 = Color.WHITE;     
                    }
                }

        // #3 BOTTOM LEFT
            if(j > 0 && i < numberOfRows-1){
                pix2 = imagingArray[i+1][j-1];
                colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));
                if (colorDifference > 65) {
                    pix1 = Color.BLACK;}
                else {
                    pix1 = Color.WHITE;     
                    }
                }
            }           

            // ABOVE
            if(i>0 && j>0){
                pix2 = imagingArray[i-1][j];
                colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));
                if (colorDifference > 65) {
                    pix1 = Color.BLACK;}
                else {
                    pix1 = Color.WHITE;     
                }

            // TOP RIGHT
            if(j < numberOfColumns-1 && i>0){
                pix2 = imagingArray[i-1][j+1];
                colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));
                if (colorDifference > 65) {
                    pix1 = Color.BLACK;}
                else {
                    pix1 = Color.WHITE;     
                }
            }
            //6  TOP LEFT
            if(j > 0 && i>0 ){
                pix2 = imagingArray[i-1][j-1];
                colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));
                if (colorDifference > 65) {
                    pix1 = Color.BLACK;}
                else {
                    pix1 = Color.WHITE;     
                }
            }

            // 7 RIGHT
            if(j<numberOfColumns-1 && i>0) {
                pix2 = imagingArray[i][j+1];
                colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));
                if (colorDifference > 65) {
                    pix1 = Color.BLACK;}
                else { 
                    pix1 = Color.WHITE;     
                }
            }
        }
            // 8 LEFT
            if(j>0 && i>0) {
                pix2 = imagingArray[i][j-1];
                colorDifference = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.getRed() - pix2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getGreen() - pix2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(pix1.getBlue() - pix2.getBlue(),2));
                if (colorDifference > 65) {
                    pix1 = Color.BLACK;}
                else { 
                    pix1 = Color.WHITE;}
            }
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: the exception should be acompanied with stack trace that has line numbers

Comment: the method in the stack trace is `doOperation` but in the pasted code it has different name

Comment: Sorry that's just a typo, where I changed the name of the method, and forgot to change it on here.

Comment: perhaps you can help us just little bit by pointing out which line is the exception thrown from? what is line number 31??

Comment: no bother, see my answer

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I updated my code with some of your suggestions, which fixed the out of bounds issue, but different errors arose.

Comment: if my answer solved the original problem, you should accept it. 
as to the new problem, my guess is that some of the cells in the matrix are not initialized. learn to use a debugger

Comment: perhaps the method doesn't need to return anything? if you intend to update `imagingArray` then it can return void. however, you read from `imagingArray` but you never update it. something like `imagingArray[i][j] = pix1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over neighboring 8 pixels using 2 nested for loops like following

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
        for(i1 = -1; i1 <= 1; i1++) {
            for(j1 = -1; j1 <= 1; j1++) {
                if(!(i1 == 0 && j1 == 0) && i + i1 >=0 && i + i1 < numberOfRows && j + j1 >= 0 and j + j1 < numberOfColumns) {
                    pix2 = imagingArray[i+i1][j+j1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or an even simpler option is to store an array of 8 elements that store the coordinate offsets for the neighbors like `[[0, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1]...]` (I will let you figure out remaining 4 offsets)

Comment: In your example, what do i1 and j1 represent?

Comment: the offset of the neighboring pixel relative to your current pixel.

Answer (score 0):

the error can occur in several places in the code, where you check for upper bounds.
for example:

```
            if (i < numberOfRows && j>0) {
                pix2 = imagingArray[i+1][j];//to the right of current pixel
```

here `i` can be equal to `numberOfRows-1` and then when you try to access `i+1` you will get the above mentioned exception

you need to remember that array indices go from `0` to `length-1`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that instead of surrounding each of the "modules" in if statements (e.g. `if (j > 0)`) you surround them in a try-catch. This means it is impossible to receive an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Doing this will look like so:

```
try {
    if (i < numberOfRows) {
        // ..do whatever you did here
    }
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // do nothing because you hit the edge
}
```

Do this for each if statement and it should work.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Doing it this way has another perk of easily seeing where the exception occurred if you want to. Just place `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` block that's effected.

Comment: [Coding by exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_by_exception) is considered an [anti pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) and bad practice

Comment: but in many cases it can save a lot of space when you know exactly what you are looking for. I created a voxel-like game before and to check the neighboring chunks I also surrounded the code blocks in `try-catch` statements. The difference is that I knew exactly what I needed to catch and why.

Comment: Of course it depends on what you are coding, in my case I would have had to surround the block with multiple if statements (or one reeeaaaallllyyyy) long one so it kind of worked out better. It's a personal preference for me, my eyes like the look of it. Besides, if you leave the `catch` blank, then it takes up the same amount of space.

Comment: readability is not about saving "space". exceptions were not designed to be part of the code flow. there are solutions if you want to reduce blocks (curly brackets) or indentation - like putting the if statements in separate method. personal preference aside, this is not an advice that gets endorsed by the professional community

Comment: I guess you're right, but it's always good to know alternative ways to code things, I thought my answer was a good way to see the concept, not nessesarily to be efficient. But I'll take it into consideration